# Difference between Ajax upload and Normal upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, upload

i have a doubt with the upload system in `PHP`.

What is the difference between Normal Upload [ without ajax ] and Ajax Upload ?

By using Javascript i can send values to the server ,is it possible in the case of Files ?

Is there any limitation for this ? and i found that so many uploaders are using FLASH for to upload FILES,
ex:Gmail,uploadify.....

How can i build a basic uploader with JQUERY/javascript ? also i heard that i cant send FILE by a XHR request.

i am using Codeigniter Framework.

`Expecting Possible duplicate or other refference`
Main Goal Of this Question is to build my own uploader for my current project[neat and clean]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, AJAX upload is basically just that, it's going through Javascript. The difference is that the page does not upload, and you can carry on with other things as it works. It generally makes for a better user experience in my opinion, it feels more seamless

On the other hand, it only works for newer browsers. Firefox, Chrome, Opera have it, but not IE (maybe Safari?). It also works well with drag and drop. I once made an image uploader inside a text editor, where it popped up a table with your currently uploaded images, you clicked one and it added it to the textbox or you dragged a new image into a box and it uploaded and displayed it straight away. It was beautiful.

Here's the plugin I used to help me

http://dropup.net/

Edit: No limitations either, you can even send plain binary data in

Answer (score 0):

well as if you want to upload the file with jquery ajax request then use ajax form plugin as well,

this link [Ajax From](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) will help you to understand and implement on your page,

but i don't know about codignighter frame work cause i don't have experience of that. And ajax is the best way to distribute the process into different parts with any extra load on the page i mean ajax request will work on the back end..

Comment: `Since it is not possible to upload files using the browser's XMLHttpRequest object, the Form Plugin uses a hidden iframe element to help with the task` - From Malsup.

Comment: You can use iframe technique to upload images without refreshing the page